# What are your Initial Impressions?

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

What are the letters in capitals below hinting at and what is their theme?

RDDHIKGHBRMH

Good luck!

Hint:

> The title provides a huge clue of where to start

Comment: Do we get any more context, story or clues besides the title? Where should a solver start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What we have here is:

> six pairs of *initials* (as hinted in the title), each of which corresponds to a **famous philosopher**.

Try to guess who before looking at the next spoiler! Their identities are:

> RD = [René Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes) (1596-1650)
>  DH = [David Hume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Hume) (1711-1776)
>  IK = [Immanuel Kant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanuel_Kant) (1724-1804)
>  GH = [George Hegel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Wilhelm_Friedrich_Hegel) (1770-1831)
>  BR = [Bertrand Russell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_Russell) (1872-1970)
>  MH = [Martin Heidegger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Heidegger) (1889-1976)
>
>  Note that the philosophers in this list have been arranged in chronological order (either by date of birth or date of death).

With this in mind, the puzzle could well be a punny nod towards:

> **[FIRST PHILOSOPHY](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/First%20Philosophy)**, a concept defined as *a study of supersensible immutable being*. In fact, very fittingly, the *first philosopher* in our list here wrote a famous work all about this subject, *[Meditations on First Philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meditations_on_First_Philosophy)* (1641).

The giveaway for me was:

> IK - assuming these were initials, there's not a whole heap of famous people with this pairing...

Comment: Congratulations

Answer (score 2):

The Answer is:

> RDD = Redding
> HIK = Hickman (Hololulu)
> GHB = Governor's Harbour (Bahamas)
> RMH = Harrisonburg Virginia
>  All airports